# I'm getting a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'", not sure why

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to change the look of a button based on whether the user has liked an image by using 1 class if he has and another class if he hasn't but I'm getting a parse error which I can not find. Of course the reason could be that I'm trying to do something that can't be done like that.

```
<a href='#' class='vote {{ Auth::user()->votes()->where("image_id", $image->id)->first() ? Auth::user()->votes()->where("image_id", $image->id)->first()->like == 1 ? "liked" : "like" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
```

Comment: What makes you think the error is in the code you have posted above? What's the full error message?

Comment: Pro Tip Break this fancy code into multiple line so you'll get the error along with line number.

Comment: You are using `condition ? condition ? val1 : val2`? :D

Comment: And your ternary operator is absolutely wrong

Comment: The error happened after writing this piece of code, if I remove it everything is dandy.

Comment: Stacking ternary statements is just asking for trouble ~ http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php#example-104

Comment: If I'm right, your logic is check if logged in user `like`-ed (via `votes` relationship) the image or not, then display corresponding word. You can do that by: `Auth::user()->votes()->where("image_id", $image->id)->first() ? (Auth::user()->votes()->where("image_id", $image->id)->first()->like == 1 ? "liked" : "like") : "like"`.

Comment: The most important thing is not make a piece of code run, but run well with improvement. Please process complex / long user logic before passing them to view.

Comment: You should rethink this code. On top of this being an ugly use of nesting ternaries, you're executing 2 SQL queries for same data here (when the image is found).

Comment: Auth is session not Model

Comment: @C2486 if you're addressing my comment, I didn't mean fetching the user twice. They're calling the votes relationship *query* twice `->votes()`. Not a preloaded property `->votes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 1 ) ? "liked" : "like" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
```

Comment: Paste as it is, and it will work for you.
I'm damn sure about it :)

Comment: After pasting this, I no longer get the error, however, my html class doesn't change after a refresh even though the database record shows that the user has liked it.

Comment: I've added your second condition with AND parameter
if record found and that have like value 1,
then 'liked' class will be applied there.
May be you're missing something.

Comment: If you want to use your code just at last else statement that also will work.
But i created it this line with optimized.

Comment: auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()
What's retrurn by this?

Comment: {"id":14,"user_id":5,"image_id":6,"vote":1,"created_at":"2018-05-21 05:03:08","updated_at":"2018-05-21 05:03:08"} this is the vote from my votes table, now since vote column is 1 it means the image has been liked.

Comment: Hey @Bobimaru ,
Then why you're putting like in query?

You should do it like this:-


<a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 1 ) ? "liked" : "like" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>

Comment: Replace after && paramter with this

auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote

And please let me know, if it's not work.

Comment: Oh my... I didn't realize I've been putting like instead of vote in the query. This works now, thanks a lot. You can put it in an answer so I can select it as solution it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <a href='#' class='vote {{ Auth::user()->votes()->where("image_id", $image->id)->first() ? (Auth::user()->votes()->where("image_id", $image->id)->first()->like == 1 ? "liked" : "like") : '' }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
```

You need to wrap with () after ? because you make 2 if statement.

Comment: Might be best if you clearly explain what you've changed; it's hard to compare while scrolling horizontally

Comment: I am still getting the same error for some reason.

Comment: It's deadly wrong. :D

Comment: ^. Also, if I'm not mistaken you're not ending the outer ternary (no `: default`)

Comment: Check my comment.

Comment: I've updated it. sorry going offline almost 12 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your code but it might be helpful for you because you missed the else condition in ternary operator.

```
<a href='#' class='vote {{ Auth::user()->votes()->where("image_id", $image->id)->first() ? (Auth::user()->votes()->where("image_id", $image->id)->first()->like == 1 ? "liked" : "like" }}):"" ' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
```